# How do i add transparency in my unity3d shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transparent, alpha, alpha-transparency

I have a shader for bending a tunnel into a curvy path. But when i'm inside that tunnel, i want the walls of the tunnel to be see-through (transparent), so that i could see the skybox and other things outside the tunnel.

[image: My spaceship travels inside this tunnel.]

I have transparency settings already coded in my shader, but that's not working. Here's my code. Please take a look,

```
Shader "WorldBend/Bend_Unlit_Segments" 
{

Properties
{
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _Emission ("Emissive Color", Color) = (0,0,0,0)
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
    _Transparency ("Transparency", Float) = 0.25
}

SubShader 
{
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    LOD 100

    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

    Pass {  
        Name "BASE"
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "BendEffect.cginc"

            struct appdata_t {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _Emission;
            float4 _Color;
            float4 _Transparency;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(BendEffect(v.vertex));
                o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord) * _Color;
                col.a = _Transparency;
                return col + _Emission;
            }
        ENDCG
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
```

The color value here is in RGBA format, the fourth value ("A") is the alpha channel which sets the transparency. 1 means opaque, 0 means transparent. Values in between, well, works just like the other RGB values.